# How to schedule a cron job to run every tuesday between specific dates of every month?

Tags: cron, ubuntu-16.04, crontab

I want to run my cron job at 4 AM on every Tuesday between 4th and 24th of every month. Can someone help me with this. It shouldnt run outside the 4-24 range. Inside this range, it should run only on Tuesdays. For example for the month of April 2019, I want my job to run only on 9th, 16th and 23rd. Any help would be much appreciated. The OS is Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a simple cron job that runs each day on the 4-24th

```
0 4 4-24 * * /bin/foo
```

with a condition to test for Tuesday.

```
[ "$(date '+%a')" = "Tue" ]
```

Combining this you have:

```
0 4 4-24 * * [ "$(date '+\%a')" = "Tue" ] && /bin/foo
```